# Fieldset Title is blank.Bug?

Tags: google-chrome, fieldset, extjs6.2

Why some fielsets title are blank? Please see images:

[image: Fieldset tittle is blank]

[image: Ok in this form]

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a regression with the latest Chrome version, as a workaround I came up with these two hacks:

```
.x-fieldset-header {
    overflow: unset;
}

.x-fieldset-header-tool-default > .x-tool-toggle {
    opacity: inherit;
}
```

the opacity hack fixes invisible arrows/checkboxes when the fieldset is set to collapsible.

Comment: Where is the best place to put thesse hacks?

Comment: Anywhere in your stylesheets